# GWT StackLayoutPanel: how to change header background color

Tags: gwt

I want to change stacklayoutpanel header back ground color using css and I tried everything.

```
.gwt-StackLayoutPanel .gwt-StackLayoutPanelHeader .gwt-StackLayoutPanelContent .gwt-StackLayoutPanelItem {  
    color: red;
    border:red;
    border-color: red;
    background:red;
    background-color:red;
}
```

But only changed the text color and I don't want that. Please can you explain how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

StackLayoutPanel wraps hour header widget/text to an internal class named Header, which is not publicly accessible. One approach is to override default clean.css .gwt-StackLayoutPanel .gwt-StackLayoutPanelHeader styles by copying it to your own css file, then appending !important to styles you want to change. 
However, better and cleaner solution is to do the following:

```
// add/insert your item first
myStackLayoutPanel.add(widget, header, size);
// retrieve the Header internal widget (AFTER ADDING!)
Widget internHeader = header.getParent();
// replace default style
internHeader.setStyleName("my_custom_style");
```

If you don't like using class css styles, you may alternatively do something like:

```
... same as above
// reset the default style
internHeader.setStyleName("");
// then add your styles programmatically
Style style = internHeader.getElement().getStyle();
style.setBackgroundColor();
etc.
```

It is important to retrieve the internal header widget after call to add/insert!

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS style is incorrect. It's trying to target classes with the following hierarchy:

```
.gwt-StackLayoutPanel 
  .gwt-StackLayoutPanelHeader 
    .gwt-StackLayoutPanelContent 
      .gwt-StackLayoutPanelItem
```

Which is completely incorrect. If you want ALL elements with those classes to have the same background color, you would write your CSS rule like this:

```
.gwt-StackLayoutPanel, 
.gwt-StackLayoutPanelHeader, 
.gwt-StackLayoutPanelContent, 
.gwt-StackLayoutPanelItem 
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You better create your own css file based on gwt's default and make changes there. You also need to exclude gwt default css from your_module.gwt.xml and put there your newly created